# Last 10 items from table from last added item

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making web-chat and I want to show last added messages at the bottom of the page and I want limit 10 last messages.

My sql query now looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chat_room=5 LIMIT 10
```

But this works not like I want. If I have 20 items in table with messages, this query selects items from 1 to 10 but I want from 10 to 20 and last messages at the bottom.

Table messages has column create_date in UNIX time format (INT)

How to change this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arnep's answer is nearly correct, however it will return a list with the last message at the top....

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE chat_room=5 
    ORDER BY your_date_column DESC 
    LIMIT 10) ilv
ORDER BY your_date_column ASC
```

Comment: +1 Good point, we all missed the bit about last messages at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You should order by the date added, as it is not guaranteed that the rows are stored and retrieved in the order you inserted them into the table. The column `your_date_column` contains the datetime of each message.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chat_room=5 ORDER BY your_date_column DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Nearly - but havnig selected the most recent 10, the OP asked for these to be sorted in ASCENDING order

Comment: Just put it into another query that will order the results ASC `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messages... ORDER BY your_date_column DESC LIMIT 10) AS sq ORDER BY your_date_column ASC`

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask for the data in the right order.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chat_room=5 ORDER BY message_ID DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Will only work one a single node with auto_increment_increment set to 1

Comment: @symcbean you are correct but if such a column exists then it is a better choice than a date field as there is never any ambiguity over which 10 are selected.  However for this example date field or Identity column it doesn't make much difference and either solution will work.  I had to guess a column name to answer the question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'there is no ambiguity' when talking about '10 most recent'. The fact is 10 highest auto ID's might not map to 10 most recent rows, and replicated multi-master setup is a good example of that. Bottom line: you want rows ordered by time, use a column with temporal datatype to order.

Comment: Fair enough.  I only put in because I was guessing at a field name.

Answer (score 2):

Just order them by an index like a timestamp or your row id.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chat_room=5 ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 10
```